# Software package to evaluate Doubly Non Central F Distribution CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

As part of my work, I need to evaluate the Cummulative distribution function (CDF) of a random variable following Doubly Non Central F Distribution (DNCF).

I can find nowhere a package to evaluate this CDF. Indeed Matlab does provide built-in functions for [Singly Non Central F Distribution](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/noncentral-f-distribution.html). The saddle point approximation of PDF of DNCF can be found in [Matlab file exchange](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45700-doubly-noncentral-f-distribution-function), but the accuracy is not very stable.

Does anyone know where I can find a package/implementation for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I typed in the following on Google

Does Wolfram Alpha support Doubly Non Central F Distribution?

and got this link

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoublyNoncentralF-Distribution.html

I don't know if it helps but the link on that page discusses it at length.